Landscape shows already installed updates
Landscape is showing already installed packages as upgrades. When i start the upgrades in landscape they get stuck in the state "in Progress". For example landscape shows the package "unifi" as upgradeable to version 8.1.127-25320-1 but version 8.3.32-26237-1 is already installed on the server. The server is running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. The same problem occurs on other servers as well with other packages. They are running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
